# Securing exec against executing adversary shell commands

Tags: php, attack-prevention, secure-coding

I have to execute my `.o` or `.out` binary file pre-compiled with `gcc`, it should be intended to let the user execute the small program so an action is made that connects with the app installed on the user's phone.

But i want to prevent other code not related to this concept from being executed at the same time. What i have is one constant that contains the specified command that must be executed.

```
<?php
     DEFINE('program', './main.out');
     exec(program);
```

Or working with a variable that acts as a pointer: `exec($executable);` ( However i think this is less secure ).

---

Another way: In a class, declaring a private constant `prep` that has the line that must be executed in the next procedure, a function, which then executes the escaped specific line. To give an example

```
    private const prep = "./main.out";

    function executeProgram()
    {
        $e = exec(escapeshellcmd(self::prep));

        exit();
    }
```

1. Is there a way to make this function(`exec`) fully private from being accessed by others?
2. How to sanitize it? using escapeshellcmd() would be ok.
3. Is it safe to use pointers for or in this function? let's say $executable
4. Is there any other risk that i must think about, then i'm thinking about the program itself?

Comment: If you're hardcoding the entire string, then you don't need to worry about attacks from not escaping it, since your own code isn't going to attack itself. If you're not hardcoding the entire string, then where is it coming from?

Answer (score 1):

For sanitization, You can refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657352/how-can-i-stop-command-injection-when-using-shell-exec-in-php7

TL;DR:

Use [**escapeshellcmd**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) for escaping full command to be executed, or [**escapeshellarg**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to escape arguments only for given command.